# Create an accept or deny action to a friend system using php mysql ajax jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i have a friend request system that allow users to send a request to others and i have a accept or deny button . but the problem is that there is something in the code that is not write and make the system to show nothing  and i do not know where is the error 
can anyone help me ?????

## this is the ajax part

```
//function for accepting freinds
function acceptFriendRequest(x){    
$.post(url,{request:"acceptFriend",reqID:x,thiswipt:thisRandNum},function{data}{
    $("#req"+x).html(data).show();
    ));
}

//function to deny friend request
function denyFriendRequest(x){
$.post(url,{request:"denyFriend",reqID:x,thiswipt:thisRandNum},function{data}{
    $("#req"+x).html(data).show();
    ));
}
```

## the php code:

```
///***************IF ACCEPT FRIEND***************//
if($_POST["request"]=="acceptFriend")
{
   $reqID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['reqID']);
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE id = '$reqID' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
   $numRow = mysql_num_rows($sql);
   if($numRow<1)
   {
       echo "An error occured";
       exit();
   }
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
       $mem1 = $row['mem1'];
       $mem2 = $row['mem2'];


   }


  //query for mem1 mem2 array
   $sql_frnd_mem1_array = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM members WHERE  user_id='$mem1' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
   $sql_frnd_mem2_array = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM members WHERE  user_id='$mem2' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_frnd_mem1_array))
   {
       $frnd_array_mem1 = $row['friend_array'];
   }
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_frnd_mem2_array))
   {
       $frnd_array_mem2 = $row['friend_array'];
   }
   $frnArrayMem1 = explode(",",$frnd_array_mem1);
   $frnArrayMem2 = explode(",", $frnd_array_mem2);

   //*******************PREVENT DUPLICATION IN id**************
   if(in_array($mem2,$frnArrayMem1))
   {
       echo "this member is already your friend!";
       exit();
   }
   if(in_array($mem1,$frnArrayMem2))
   {
       echo "this member is already your friend!";
       exit();
   }

   // puting each other in friend array field
   if($frnd_array_mem1 !="" )
   {
       $frnd_array_mem1 ="$frnd_array_mem1, $mem2";
   }
   else
   {
       $frnd_array_mem1 = "$mem2";
   }
   if($frnd_array_mem2 !="" )
   {
       $frnd_array_mem2 ="$frnd_array_mem2, $mem1";
   }
   else
   {
       $frnd_array_mem2 = "$mem1";
   }
   $UpdateArrayMme1 = mysql_query("UPDATE  members SET friend_array = '$frnd_array_mem1' WHERE user_id = '$mem1'") or die(mysql_error());
    $UpdateArrayMme2 = mysql_query("UPDATE  members SET friend_array = '$frnd_array_mem2' WHERE user_id = '$mem2'") or die(mysql_error());
    $deleteThisPendingRequest =mysql_query("DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE id = '$reqID' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());  
    echo "you are now friend with this member!";
    exit();
}
//*********deny Friend***************
if($_POST['request']=="denyFriend")
{
    $reqID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['reqID']);
    $deletethisPendigRequest = mysql_query("DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id = '$reqID' LIMIT 1 ")or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Request Denied";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: what kind of error message are you getting? is the php not executing? are you getting a javascript error (check your error console)? just posting your code and asking people to look for bugs doesn't seem like a good fit for this site.

Comment: presumably all those queries are going to return either no rows, or one row... using a while() loop to fetch those 0/1 rows is a major symptom to cargo-cult programming. You really really really also need to learn about database normalization, which will reduce your entire pile code down to just two queries and maybe 5-6 lines of code...

Comment: sir this is my first website that i am trying to build  and within the cycle of development i will get a big experience from people like you for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong in your code :

on

```
    //function for accepting freinds
    function acceptFriendRequest(x){    
    $.post(url,{request:"acceptFriend",reqID:x,thiswipt:thisRandNum},function{data}{
        $("#req"+x).html(data).show();
        ));     
    }
```

and

```
    //function to deny friend request
    function denyFriendRequest(x){
    $.post(url,{request:"denyFriend",reqID:x,thiswipt:thisRandNum},function{data}{
        $("#req"+x).html(data).show();
        ));
    }
```

`function{data}{}` should be `function(data){}`